# Missing dataframe column percentage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, missing-data

I have a dataset with 21 columns there are 2 columns that has 25% missing values, I'm reluctant to drop them or not?
Is it make sence to drop columns that has more than 20% of its data as missing, or how can I determine the percentage of missing values that decide to drop the column

I dropped the columns that have 20% or more missing values, I am expecting to know the best way to determine this percentage amount for example: should I use 20% or 40% or higher?

Comment: For future reference, it would be helpful for us to help you if you include details providing context about the problem you are trying to answer. That being said, I vote to close because you're asking for an opinion. If you would like statistical consultation, please post in CrossValidated.

Answer (score 0):

One approach

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, 21 * 5).reshape(-1, 21)).replace({0: np.nan})
print('Original df\n',df)
df = df.loc[:, df.isna().sum().div(df.shape[0]).le(0.25)]
print('\nResult df without columns > 25% missing values\n',df)
```

```
Original df
     0   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
0  2.0 NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  3.0  2.0  NaN  1.0  4.0  NaN  4.0  3.0  1.0  3.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  3.0 NaN  3.0  NaN  4.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  2.0  1.0  4.0  NaN  2.0  3.0  NaN  4.0  NaN  2.0
2  4.0 NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  4.0  1.0  4.0  4.0  1.0  3.0  2.0  2.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  3.0  4.0
3  2.0 NaN  4.0  4.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN  1.0  4.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  4.0  1.0
4  4.0 NaN  4.0  3.0  4.0  1.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN

Result df without columns > 25% missing values
     0    2    5    6    9    11   12   13   15   18   19
0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  4.0  4.0  3.0  1.0  4.0  1.0  4.0
1  3.0  3.0  NaN  3.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  2.0  4.0  NaN
2  4.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  4.0  1.0  3.0  2.0  4.0  2.0  3.0
3  2.0  4.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  1.0  4.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
4  4.0  4.0  1.0  4.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I determine the percentage of missing values

You might do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3],'Y':[4,5,None],'Z':[7,None,None]})
missing = df.isnull().mean() * 100
print(missing)
```

output

```
X     0.000000
Y    33.333333
Z    66.666667
dtype: float64
```

Explanation: `.isnull()` gives `True` or `False`, as they are treated as `1` and `0` when doing arithemtic, getting `mean` will give value `0.0` (nothing missing) to `1.0` (all missing) which you need to multiply by `100` to get percentage.